# Customizing css file to display icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I've been trying to customise an icon to show a logo in my header, but I don't know how to set up correctly my css file for this. I'm using Bootstrap, and the logo is stored in my static folder: */static/img/logo.jpg*

First of, my code loads the bootstrap css file first, then my custom css file.

Then my html file references this:

```
...

<div class="page-header" >
    <div class="container">
    <h1><a href="https://mywebsite.com"><i class="icon-logo"></i></a></h1>

...
```

My css file so far contains this:

```
...

.page-header {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 11;
}

.container {
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
}

.container h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a {
  position: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

...
```

What should I add to the css file to customise and display the logo?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you wan't to do.

If you want the style the icon, just apply your CSS to that : `.page-header .container h1 a i`

But I think you wan't to replace the icon, so if you wan't to display your logo, and then style it, you could set your html like that :

```
<div class="page-header" >
    <div class="container">
        <h1><a href="https://mywebsite.com"><img src="/static/img/logo.jpg" alt"logo">
        </a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then apply your style to `.page-header .container h1 a img`

And it should be fine.